# show and hide a div and insert after some other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a div with style display none and later I am setting this to null.
And I am adding after some other div . But this is shown. Can you help ?

```
$("#SecondDiv").css("display : null");
$("#SecondDiv").insertAfter($("#FirstDiv"));


    <div class="note note-warning" id="SecondtDiv" style="display: none">
        <div class="block-warning">
            <h4 class="block"> <i class="demo-icon icon-attention-1 fa"></i> Error! </h4>
            <p>Settings is not updated</p>
        </div>
    </div>    

    <div class="table-responsive" id="FirstDiv">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `.css("display : null")` which is already incorrect usage of the function but try using `.show()` like this:

```
$("#SecondDiv").show();
```

Also, the id of the div you are trying to reference in the markup is misspelt I assume as SecondtDiv when it should be SecondDiv.

Comment: I want to set my display property to show and insert the div after the second div

Answer (score 2):

This is not valid CSS:

```
$("#SecondDiv").css("display : null");
```

So what's happening is that the [display style](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/display) is defaulting to 'inline'; You're gonna want to switch this to :

```
$("#SecondDiv").css("display", "none");
```

Comment: .css() takes two parameters, one for the property and one for the value. http://api.jquery.com/css/